# http 301 redirection issue

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I'm a little bit lost with a redirection.

I want mysite.com, www.mysite.com and www.mysite.co.uk to redirect to mysite.co.uk.

In Apache, I wrote this for mysite.co.uk in order to redirect www to the root domain:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And for mysite.com, I wrote this redirect to mysite.co.uk:

```
ServerName www.mysite.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://mysite.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This way, I can make the redirection work properly from www.mysite.com to mysite.co.uk, but it doesn't work for mysite.com too mysite.co.uk (without the www) at the same time. Could someone tell me how to make all my redirections work in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your config for www.mysite.com, add this;

```
ServerAlias mysite.com
```

This will make the VirtualHost respond to that hostname too, and since the only configuration in that VirtualHost entry is to redirect, it will. For brownie points, you could also add in;

```
ServerAlias www.mysite.co.uk
```

And ditch the RewriteRules in your first VirtualHost entry altogether.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the apache directive:

```
 Redirect
```

OR

```
 RedirectPermanent
```

See http://httpd.apache.org for more information.